# Is it possible for mobile devices to connect to a far away ASN?

Tags: bgp, networking

I am trying to understand how the internet connection of mobile devices is done. Knowing that BGP is used for the communication, I would like to know is it possible for the mobile device to connect to a ASN that is located two states away from my current location?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is the same way that you PC can. You connect to your ISP, and your ISP uses BGP to route the packets to the next ISP on the way to the destination.

Comment: I have looked at a user location login history, it looks like he did login using his mobile but the location is way off from his current location, so I want to understand is this normal that user connected to a far away ASN (approximately 500km)? @RonMaupin

Comment: ASes do not have a physical location. Some ASes span the world. You may be getting information about the address of the company with the AS registration, but that really means nothing about where the AS is or is not.

Answer (score 3):

As @ronmaupin points out, ASes do not have a particular location.  Some ASes may span the globe.  The registered address for the AS is just where the owner is, but the network(s) could be anywhere and in multiple locations.